# Fill a mesh with particle hair

Tags: mesh, rigging, particles

I want to take a low poly hair mesh and fill it with particle hair on the inside. This can technically be done by emitting the hair from the faces of the mesh (and flipping normals so they face the correct way) but then the hair won't be in the proper direction. I want the hair to originate from a point, and then taper to the tip of mesh spikes.

The particle hair also needs to  move with the mesh, which will be rigged.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: Does selecting *emit from > volume* do what you need?

Comment: I'm afraid not. That makes the strands emit from inside the mesh instead of from its faces, but it doesn't help with direction.