# Can You Convert Hair Made From a Mesh Into a Particle System

Tags: mesh, particles, hair, conversion

I have been scouring the internet for an answer to this, but I can't seem to find one. I extracted a couple characters from Overwatch, these being: Mcree, Soldier: 76, Torbjörn, and Junkrat. In the cinematics for the game, their hair is a lot more detailed and realistic then it is in the game, for example:[image] This is the cinematic
[image] and this is the game

What I want to do is make their hair from the game look exactly, if not very, very, very, close to the cinematic, and I really don't want to have to manually shape it. Is there anyway I can possibly convert their hair from the game into a particle system. I would include the Blend file of Junkrat, since he is the one I am currently working on, but I am unsure on how to that.I have seen other people succeed with this task, for example:[image] I would really appreciate any help with this.

P.S. Junkrat seems to be only one with a full head, all the characters head's seem to stop at the hairline. Also the other people who manage to do this seem to use vertex groups, and some with interpolated hair.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94732/particles-to-follow-my-mesh-hair-style This is a similar question, although i think no solution was found there: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35473/fill-a-mesh-with-particle-hair

Comment: Thank you Mr. Roth, but unfortunetly this did not help. Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine if you bake maps from the solid hair, you can use those same masks for effects. I haven't done this before but that's where I'd start, especially baking a world position map.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this sounds very helpful, but is there any way you could guide me through it because I'm not very sure what you mean? Here is the Blend file incase you need it: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6299" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6299/)